# Can you Display an image that is part of firebase database on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to display my firebase database but I want each entry to have an image attached to it. Is it possible to have the variable type "Image" in my Exercise Class? If so how would display it when I run it on my app. I can display all the Strings but when I tried to display the images it would crash.

[DATABASE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dYff.png)

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Exercise exercise = list.get(position);
    holder.exerciseName.setText(exercise.getExerciseName());
    holder.muscleGroupName.setText(exercise.getMuscleGroupName());
    holder.equipmentName.setText(exercise.getEquipmentName());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(exercise.getImage());
}

public class Exercise {
    String exerciseName, muscleGroupName, equipmentName;
    Image image;

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getExerciseName() {
        return exerciseName;
    }

    public String getMuscleGroupName() {
        return muscleGroupName;
    }

    public String getEquipmentName() {
        return equipmentName;
    }
}
```

[What I'm trying to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwELS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your build.gradle(Module: app) under `dependencies` add this library:

```
dependencies {

 
 //other dependencies 
 
 //GLide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

re write your class as:

```
public class Exercise {

        String exerciseName, muscleGroupName, equipmentName,image;

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getExerciseName() {
            return exerciseName;
        }

        public String getMuscleGroupName() {
            return muscleGroupName;
        }

        public String getEquipmentName() {
            return equipmentName;
        }

    }
```

Use it this way:

```
Exercise exercise = list.get(position);
                    holder.exerciseName.setText(exercise.getExerciseName());
                    holder.muscleGroupName.setText(exercise.getMuscleGroupName());
                    holder.equipmentName.setText(exercise.getEquipmentName());
                    Glide.with(holder.imageView)
                            .load(exercise.getImage())
                            .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: please accept if it does ans your question.

Comment: would I still save the photo the same way? right now it's using a token from the firebase storage.

Comment: Never Mind I got it to work. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could hold it in the db as an array of bytes.  But I really wouldn't suggest storing images in a database that way.  Usually you put a URL or filename to the image, then load the image from there.

Comment: so would I put the url from the actual source of the photo?